How can I fix this MATE error from the code below?
So I am continuing my previous code, in conclusion I am doing a bank (as a work for university). So, now the class name is CuentaBancaria.java. The block code is the following:

package fp2.poo.pfpooWFG8420;


import fp2.poo.utilidades.CuentaBancariaInterfaz;
import fp2.poo.utilidades.SaldoInterfaz;
import fp2.poo.utilidades.Excepciones.OperacionNoPermitidaExcepcion;
import  fp2.poo.pfpooWFG8420.Titular;
import fp2.poo.utilidades.TelefonoInterfaz;
import fp2.poo.utilidades.CorreoElectronicoInterfaz;
import  fp2.poo.pfpooWFG8420.NumeroDeCuenta;
import  fp2.poo.pfpooWFG8420.Saldo;

/**
 * Implementacion de la clase CuentaBancaria a partir de una
 * interfaz
 *
 */

public class CuentaBancaria implements CuentaBancariaInterfaz {

    // Atributos

    private Saldo saldo;
    private NumeroDeCuenta numeroDeCuenta;
    private Titular titular;
    
    // Constructor

     /**
     * Constructor de CuentaBancaria
     *
     * @see CuentaBancaria#CuentaBancaria()
     */
    public CuentaBancaria() {
    this.saldo = new Saldo();
    this.numeroDeCuenta = new NumeroDeCuenta();
    this.titular = new Titular();
    }
    
    // Metodos

    // Hereda comentarios de documentacion
    public void setSaldo(Saldo saldo) {
    this.saldo = saldo;
    }

    // Hereda comentarios de documentacion
    public Saldo getSaldo() {
    return this.saldo;
    }

    // Hereda comentarios de documentacion
    public void setNumeroDeCuenta(NumeroDeCuenta numeroDeCuenta) {
    this.numeroDeCuenta = numeroDeCuenta;
    }

    // Hereda comentarios de documentacion
    public NumeroDeCuenta getNumeroDeCuenta() {
    return this.numeroDeCuenta;
    }

    // Hereda comentarios de documentacion
    public void setTitular(Titular titular) {
    this.titular = titular;
    }

    // Hereda comentarios de documentacion
    public Titular getTitular() {
    return this.titular;
    }

    
}


I recicled this from another work I did weeks ago, and modified it a little bit, with the needed things. So I compiled it, I do not know yet If I have code mistakes, and the MATE Terminal put the following error:
CuentaBancaria is not abstract and does not override abstract method setTitular(TitularInterfaz) in CuentaBancariaInterfaz
public class CuentaBancaria implements CuentaBancariaInterfaz {
So what I tried was fixing it the same way I did previously with another class which was changing some stuff, and looking If there were any destinations put wrongly. I expected that it was gonna be that, and indeed it was partially, the other errors I fixed it because the makefile I made, I forgot to put ./bin/fp2/poo/pfpooWFG8420/Saldo.class, though this is not that so I do not know a way that can fix it everytime.
I will keep try to and If I fix it, I will post it. Thank you for looking on it if you do so, and thanks for the help!

Well, do you have an interface called TitularInterfaz that the Titular class implements? Because the error is telling you that that's what setTitular() expects to receive as a parameter, because that's how it's defined in CuentaBancariaInterfaz. But your implementation in CuentaBancaria expects a Titular, so the method signature is different there. Note that if there was any other class that implemented TitularInterfaz then you couldn't use it as a parameter to CuentaBancaria.setTitular(), but the CuentaBancariaInterfaz interface requires that you are able to.

Yes I do, all interfaces compiled correctly and are .class

Well, then as I said, the classes that implement the interfaces need to match the method definitions in the interface.

Okay, I am gonna now look on that, thanks for the help!

Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Indeed, I was going to put Error on MATE terminal Ubuntu Simulator, but no, the page does not allow me to, so I am not able to do it so. Either way, my issue has been fixed, so thanks for the tip!

You don't override the correct method from your interface. You override setTitular(Titular) but the interface specifies setTitular(TitularInterfaz). This is what the error message also shows you by saying you don't override the correct method.
So you need to change the method defined in your interface to the first signature.

Or adapt the method in the class to match the definition in the interface

I see now that on the interface is:  setTitular(TitularInterfaz titular), not what I've put, ty for the tip and help!

So to fix code, was what the other people said:
import fp2.poo.utilidades.CuentaBancariaInterfaz;
import fp2.poo.pfpooWFG8420.Saldo;
import fp2.poo.utilidades.SaldoInterfaz;
import fp2.poo.utilidades.Excepciones.OperacionNoPermitidaExcepcion;
import fp2.poo.pfpooWFG8420.Titular;
import fp2.poo.utilidades.TitularInterfaz;
import fp2.poo.pfpooWFG8420.NumeroDeCuenta;
import fp2.poo.utilidades.NumeroDeCuentaInterfaz;

I reorganized, and put the good and correct imports and the code had more code than needed and I just simplified as I was told. Thanks for those who helped me, couldnt have done that without them.
